# To check a function is one-one onto or not

Tags: real-analysis

The continuous function from real number to real number $f(x) = ((x^2) +1)^{2008}$

Is this one - one onto or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)= (x^2 +1 )^{2008}$

$f(1) = (1^2 +1 )^{2008}$

$f(-1) = ((-1)^2 +1)^{2008}$

But $1^2 = (-1)^2 = 1$

So $f(1)=f(-1)$

No, it isn't.

Comment: And what about onto?

Answer (score 1):

one one- NO

because f(1) =f(-1) = $2^{2008}$

and not onto because: f(x) >= 0 for all x
there for $\forall x \in R : f(x) \neq -1$

Comment: Thankyou , it is helpful